# busy indicator box using Windows Form

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, user-interface

I want to make busy indicator loading box using Windows Form something like this

[image]

I am totaly blank on UI side so please advice me how to make this kind of UI.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

create a new form lets say Form2, with FormBorderStyle set to none and with Busy indicator content then use it like:

```
//Here Application Gets Busy
Form2 busy = new Form2();
Form1.Opacity = 0.5
busy.ShowDialog();

//Not Busy Any More
busy.Close();
busy.Dispose();
```

Comment: what about opacity of main form

Comment: @DarshanPatel I edited the code and added the opacity

Comment: But, how you execute codes after ShowDialog()? Afaik codes after ShowDialog() runs once from is closed